# Unable to scrape all of the items

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, scrapy

With the help of selenium and scrapy, I'm  getting only 12 items out of 487 items. How to scrape all the items. I can't identify what's my wrong here. Anyone's help is appreciated.

[URL](https://www.arp.fr/produits-portables-tablettes-ordinateurs-portables/?queryString=JTdCJTIyYXJlYUlkJTIyJTNBJTIyMkVEODhGMjctOTNFOS00NzQzLUI3NDYtRUNFQUJENUZFRDA4JTIyJTJDJTIyaXNRdWVyeSUyMiUzQWZhbHNlJTJDJTIyc29ydEF0dHJpYnV0ZSUyMiUzQW51bGwlMkMlMjJzb3J0RGlyZWN0aW9uJTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMnBhZ2VubyUyMiUzQSUyMjElMjIlMkMlMjJwZXJQYWdlJTIyJTNBJTIyMTIlMjIlMkMlMjJ2YWx1ZXMlMjIlM0ElNUIlNUQlMkMlMjJwcm9kdWN0SWRzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTJDJTIycGFydG5lcklkJTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElNUJudWxsJTJDbnVsbCUyQ251bGwlNUQlN0Q=&page=1&productfilter=&sort=null)

MY CODE:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from time import sleep


class CpcuSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'cp'
    allowed_domains = ['www.arp.fr']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.arp.fr/produits-portables-tablettes-ordinateurs-portables/?queryString=JTdCJTIyYXJlYUlkJTIyJTNBJTIyMkVEODhGMjctOTNFOS00NzQzLUI3NDYtRUNFQUJENUZFRDA4JTIyJTJDJTIyaXNRdWVyeSUyMiUzQWZhbHNlJTJDJTIyc29ydEF0dHJpYnV0ZSUyMiUzQW51bGwlMkMlMjJzb3J0RGlyZWN0aW9uJTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMnBhZ2VubyUyMiUzQSUyMjElMjIlMkMlMjJwZXJQYWdlJTIyJTNBJTIyMTIlMjIlMkMlMjJ2YWx1ZXMlMjIlM0ElNUIlNUQlMkMlMjJwcm9kdWN0SWRzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTJDJTIycGFydG5lcklkJTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElNUJudWxsJTJDbnVsbCUyQ251bGwlNUQlN0Q=&page='+str(x)+'&productfilter=&sort=null' for x in range(1,6)]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="rasEpicTitle rasElementReaction"]'), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="fielddata"]/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        # this page loads
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
        
        print(dir(self.driver))
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        # self.driver.quit()

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        sleep(5)

        title = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        #for list_node in lists.xpath('//*[@class="rasEpicBoxContainer"]'):
            
        yield{
            'Title': title.xpath('//*[@title="028001007"]/text()').get()
        }
        #self.driver.close()
```

Comment: Since the site is loaded after opening, you must first open it with google chrome web driver using selenium and click the buttons one by one and proceed, then you can pull all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many errors in your code starting `start_urls`. If you check website you'll find that pagination doesn't work with URL. For example, you can't load third page with `https://www.arp.fr/produits-portables-tablettes-ordinateurs-portables/?queryString=JTdCJTIyYXJlYUlkJTIyJTNBJTIyMkVEODhGMjctOTNFOS00NzQzLUI3NDYtRUNFQUJENUZFRDA4JTIyJTJDJTIyaXNRdWVyeSUyMiUzQWZhbHNlJTJDJTIyc29ydEF0dHJpYnV0ZSUyMiUzQW51bGwlMkMlMjJzb3J0RGlyZWN0aW9uJTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMnBhZ2VubyUyMiUzQSUyMjElMjIlMkMlMjJwZXJQYWdlJTIyJTNBJTIyMTIlMjIlMkMlMjJ2YWx1ZXMlMjIlM0ElNUIlNUQlMkMlMjJwcm9kdWN0SWRzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTJDJTIycGFydG5lcklkJTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElNUJudWxsJTJDbnVsbCUyQ251bGwlNUQlN0Q=&page=3&productfilter=&sort=null`. You'll get a FIRST page instead.

I recommend to use another approach: emulate Javascript calls in your Scrapy spider. Internally website uses a call to a special URL to receive JSON and next show it to you. We can try to perform same actions:

```
import scrapy
import json
import base64
import urllib
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse # to update response from a string
import chompjs # to parse Javascript object


def generate_query_string(query):
    # Website send pagination and a query string using special HTTP header
    # This header is Base64 encoded and URL encoded
    query_string_raw = json.dumps(query)
    query_string_urlencoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query_string_raw)
    query_string = base64.b64encode(query_string_urlencoded.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
    return query_string

class ArpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = '68943284'
    # I got above query params from your URL using online Base64 decoder and next online URL encoder
    # Most interesting that we can set 500 results per page and get everything in a SINGLE call!
    query = {
        "areaId": "2ED88F27-93E9-4743-B746-ECEABD5FED08", 
        "isQuery": False, 
        "sortAttribute": None, 
        "sortDirection": None, 
        "pageno": "1", 
        "perPage": "500", 
        "values": [], 
        "productIds": ["5267337-05", "5393345-05", "5400545-05", "5400812-05", "5404575-05", "5409557-05", "5410466-05", "5412282-05", "5412314-05", "5412318-05", "5412323-05", "5421276-05"],
        "partnerId": None, 
        "options": [None, None, None]
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.arp.fr/filter/page.json',
            headers={
                'queryString': generate_query_string(self.query),
            },
            callback=self.parse
        )
    
    def parse(self, response):
        # with open('Samples/Arp.json', 'wb') as f:
        #    f.write(response.body)
        # We need to parse JSON response and get HTML code from it
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        # print(data['products'])
        response = HtmlResponse(url="My URL", body=data['products'], encoding='utf-8')
        # Now we need to parse HTML and get Javascript object with all data we need
        javascript = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "dataLayer.push")]/text()').re_first(r'dataLayer\.push\(([\s\S]+?)\);')
        if javascript:
            data = chompjs.parse_js_object(javascript)
            for item in data['ecommerce']['impressions']:
                name = item['name']
                price = item['price']
                print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Everything is ok but I'm not understanding  the usage of chompjs. How to install it. I tried to pip install to my scrapy virtual environment but it shows errors. can you help me providing  alternative of chompjs or how to pip install? It's community is very low. I searched on it nothing is found as helpful.

Comment: @Mohna I used chompjs because website uses single quotes in `javascript` object (and `json.loads()` can't parse it). You can use another library for that or write your own parsing logic.

Comment: Thanks. It's producing output nicely. But I'm not understanding the meaning of "My URL" and  ? ; from regex portion. Will you explain a little bit?

Comment: and  meaning of re_first and why?

Comment: @Mohna `My URL` is just a string that will be used as a BASE URL for loaded HTML.

Comment: @Mohna Regular expression is just an instruction to get everything between `dataLayer.push(` and `);`